# Is it possible to create worksheet specific named ranges in VBA XL using Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

Is it possible to create a worksheet specific named range in VBA XL (16.4) running on Mac?

I would like to be able to name a cell on several different sheets. But when giving "A1" a name on sheet1, the same name can not be used on Sheet2.

I tried the name manager/"Define name", accesed via tool bar -> Formulas. I have not written any code to try and name the ranges.

Comment: Yes, it is. What did you try, and what happened?

Comment: Welcome to SO. House rules are to post some code or at least explain what you've tried already as its a help site rather than a code writing service. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi thank you for quick replys! 
I used the name manager/"Define name", accesed via tool bar -> Formulas. 

I have not written any code to try and name the ranges.

Comment: For Mac you might find this useful: https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 different ways to define names:

1. Locally in a worksheet's scope:

   ```
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Names.Add Name:="name", RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R1C1"
   ```
2. Globally in a workbook's scope:

   ```
    ThisWorkbook.Names.Add Name:="global", RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R1C2"
   ```

If you define them locally the same name can exist in each worksheet's scope once. So this is possible:

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Names.Add Name:="name", RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet1!R1C1"
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Names.Add Name:="name", RefersToR1C1:="=Sheet2!R1C1"
```

The same can be done with the toolbar choosing the correct scope.

[image]
*<sup>Image 1: Define new name dialog (sorry for the german screenshot, Arbeitsmappe = Workbook, Tabelle1 = Sheet1, …).</sup>*

Comment: Thank you very much! The toolbar you showed screenshot of is not optional in my version of XL running on mac. The name manager has very limited function.